# Retrieve source of a dynamic website

Tags: dynamic

How to retrieve source of a dynamic website just like what we do to save the page in the web browser?

--P.S.1 This is called "Generated Source" in Web Developer in Firefox, which is the source after running all Ajax and JavaScript codes.

--P.S.2 I have tried wget and curl but they did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You question is unclear. Did you explore [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/)

Comment: Well you will have to give us more info. Which site, do you need to POST some data? If so can use cURL for posting data, also which language do you use? JAVA, PHP, C#...

Comment: Well, the information can only be accessed for certain accounts so the URL of the site may not be useful... The URL is in this form: http://blahblahblah.com/XXX.action?parameter1=xx&parameter2=xx; it works in Firefox when I saved the page but not in wget or curl.